# Android Page Flipping pedals

Tags: android

How does one design an app to work with the page flipping footing pedals for reading pages/pdfs and how does one tell an app from another app to change the "page"? I'm looking at making some apps to do some stuff like foot controlling pdf page changes(page up, etc) and other things and would like

What I am talking about is simply being able to have hands free reading and need either design an app that accepts wireless/remote page flipping and/or interact with another app.

Does android support some simple interface too allow this, and if so, where can I find some more info on it? (there are BT pedals that supposedly work well for this and I want to know how this is done on by the app side and the pedal side)

Thanks.

Comment: What does `flipping footing pedals` means??

Comment: @VivekMishra Um, there are pedals that you can use to turn pages rather than fingers. Check them out on amazon if you don't know what I'm talking about.

Comment: You should have reference this in your question . Not everyone know what that means and if you can post a screenshot that would be much better.